# Question about taos shell use source command

Tags: tdengine

What is the maximum file size for taos source 'filename' command? For my project, the data file is huge and I'm afraid of being interrupted within data transferring.

Answer (score -1):

In general, there is no limitation in TDengine, but I think you should take care of your system hardware capabilities.